# The order of $a$ if $a^x \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $p > 2$ be a prime and $x > 0$ be not divisible by $3$. Prove that if $a^x \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$, then $r = 2x$ is the minimal value of $r$ such that $a^r \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$.

I was wondering if the above was true and how to prove it. It didn't seem very obvious to me that it is minimal.

Comment: You have to assume more.. Like $x,p>0$ and $p\neq 2$ and whatsoever.. After assuming that, note that $Z/pZ$ has a cyclic multiplicative subgroup

Comment: If $a^x \equiv -1\bmod p$ then $a^{2x} \equiv 1 \bmod p$ and $a^{3x}\equiv  -1 \bmod p$, but $r = 6x$ isn't the order of $a$ modulo $p$. So you need to assume $x$ is prime for being sure that $order_{\bmod p}(a) = 2x$

Comment: Even if $x$ is prime this is still clearly false for $a \equiv -1 \pmod p$.

Comment: @ErickWong What about not divisible by $3$?

Comment: @user19405892 Huh?  If $a = -1$ then the antecedent is true for any odd $x$, but the consequent can't possibly be true for more than one value of $x$.  Divisibility by $3$ is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @ErickWong do you agree with my answer now, or do you think there is something more to say

Answer (score 1):

Let $k=ord_p(a)$. Then, 
$$a^{x}=-1 \pmod{p}$$
if and only if
$$k|2x \mbox{ and } k \nmid x$$
This implies that $k$ is even. Writing $k=2k'$ we must have $k'|x$ and $2k' \nmid x$.

This yields a simple way of constructing counterexamples. Pick $p$ any prime, and pick an element $a$ of order $4l+2$. Then any odd multiple $x$ of $2l+1$ is a counterexample.

Note that for any prime $p$ of the form $4l+3$, a primitive element has order exactly $4l+2$, and primitive elements exists.

Choosing $x$ not divisible by 3 doesn't help, and we can pick $l$ of the form $3s+2$ in the above construction, and $x$ a multiple of $2l+1$ which is not divisible $3$.

For an explicit counterexample, pick $p=11$, $a=2$ and $x=15$.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a solution $x$ to $a^x \equiv -1 \bmod p$, then you can call $\text{ preorder}_{-1 \bmod p} (a)$ the minimal such $x$.

If it exists, you have the property that $2 \text{ preorder}_{-1 \bmod p} (a) = \text{ order}_{\bmod p} (a) $ and hence $x = (2n+1)\text{ preorder}_{-1 \bmod p} (a)$.

- Proof : let $ r = \min \{y, a^y \bmod 1 \equiv p\}$ and $ s = \min \{z, a^z  \equiv -1\bmod  p\}$, then $a^{2s} \equiv 1 \bmod p$ so that $r \le 2s$, and $a^{r-s} \equiv -1 \bmod p$ so that $s \le r-s$, thus $r = 2s$.  And if $a^x \equiv -1 \bmod p$ then $r | x-s$ so that $x = s+ nr = (2n+1)s$

Thus it is not true in general that $\text{ order}_{\bmod p} (a)  = 2x$ , take for example $x = 3 \text{ preorder}_{-1 \bmod p} (a)$.

And only in some cases you can show that $order_{\bmod p}(a) = 2x$, for example if $x$ is prime and $a \not \equiv -1 \bmod p$.